# retrieve matching and non matching rows from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario

Table income has following column

```
ID     Inc_amt    Trans_date

1      100         9/24/2014

2      200         9/24/2014

3      300          9/25/2015
```

Table expense has following column

```
ID    exp_amt   Trans_date

2     100         9/24/2014

3     200         9/24/2014

4     400         9/25/2014
```

What I need is that for say trans_date = 9/24/2014,  I need the following output.  Here ID is the common key for both tables

```
ID   inc_amt   exp_amt  trans_date  

1     100       null     9/24/2014

2     200       100      9/24/2014

3    null       200      9/24/2014
```

I am confused as to what join to do .  I am able to get both matched and mismatched rows , but when I add date check condition , then it gives only matching rows for that date of 9/24/2014

Comment: This might be something you consider doing in a single table to make aggregations/calculations against the data easier in the long run.  You could easily have a single amount column with either negative amounts representing expenses or a second column to indicate whether the item is an income or expense.

Answer (score 0):

you need to left join the two tables to a base table that has the id's from both tables. 
when you left join a table it will join to any existing id's so you need to union the two tables to get all id's then join to them, then filter by date.

so something like this

### Query:

```
SELECT t.id, i.inc_amt, e.exp_amt, t.trans_date
FROM 
(   SELECT id, trans_date FROM income
    UNION 
    SELECT id, trans_date FROM expense
) t
LEFT JOIN income i ON i.id = t.id AND i.trans_date = '9/24/2014'
LEFT JOIN expense e ON t.id = e.id AND e.trans_date = '9/24/2014'
WHERE t.trans_date = '9/24/2014';
```

### Output:

```
+----+---------+---------+------------+
| id | inc_amt | exp_amt | trans_date |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 |     100 |     null| 9/24/2014  |
|  2 |     200 |     100 | 9/24/2014  |
|  3 |     null|     200 | 9/24/2014  |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try and let you know

Comment: @RajeevNair you are welcome! if this solved your issue i would greatly appreciate it if you would [**ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer! I'll reciprocate a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by union all income|expense left outer join and conditional right outer join.

```
SELECT inc.id
    ,inc.inc_amt
    ,exp.exp_amt
    ,inc.trans_date
FROM income inc
LEFT OUTER JOIN expense exp ON inc.id = exp.id
WHERE (inc.trans_date = '2014-09-24')

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT exp.id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN inc.trans_date <> '2014-09-24'
                THEN NULL
            END
        ,exp.exp_amt
        ,exp.trans_date
    FROM income inc
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN expense exp ON inc.id = exp.id
    WHERE (
            exp.trans_date = '2014-09-24'
            AND inc.trans_date <> '2014-09-24'
            )
    )
ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f94e6/1)

Comment: how did you test the code ? I have tested in my local, It is working fine. I couldn't give an sqlfiddle link since the site itself is down now! and right outer join is not supported in ideone ..

Comment: i tested on my local and it returned no results.. i woulda done the sql fiddle too but yea the site is down. :/